# Xamarin iOS - handle notifications cleared

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications

When using remote notifications, I am caching the IDs of notifications that I have received. However, when a user clicks the "Clear" button in notifications centre, I have no idea that the notification was removed. Thus I am unable to display a notification again, because it is still cached in my list, although it was already removed from the notification centre. Is there a way how to determine if a notification was cleared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Unfortunately iOS gives no way for your app to know what goes on in the notification center unless the user clicks the notification to open your app. It is pretty frustrating for me but there is not much you can do about it.

*Edit: As of iOS 10, with the new `UNUserNotificationCenter`, your app now has limited access to [work with](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios10/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications/#Notification_Management) notifications in the notification center (I am pretty sure, have not tried it myself), but it still would not help you figure out when a user clears your notification.